# Unable to cast COM object of type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to interface type

Tags: asp.net, webforms, report, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

seeking for help regarding on crystal report. I'm working on a project using asp.net webforms with crystal report... actually the project is working on my local testing but when I deployed it on our test server, results error shows like this "**Unable to cast COM object of type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to interface type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ISCRReportSource'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{31E7715A-8AD0-4D1C-958E-C1BE0A6F2D0C}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).**"

immediate response is highly appreciated. regards

Comment: on server crystal report installed?

Comment: yes it was installed

Answer (score 1):

My own question my answer... I just fix the said error by down grading version of crystal report on my dev environment matching on the version installed on the staging/testing server.